# Office API javascript

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I am developing a web-addin for Word. If I have the following text in a Word document:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus interdum pulvinar ornare. Aliquam erat dolor, varius vitae congue in, dictum at sapien. Maecenas convallis nulla vitae ex condimentum, ac elementum sapien ullamcorper.
>
> Nulla et arcu nulla. Praesent ac nunc condimentum, gravida elit at, egestas purus. Nunc dictum sem nec lacus ultrices hendrerit. Sed vitae lacus augue. Aenean porttitor ex quis mi ultricies mollis. Nunc fringilla facilisis ante in luctus. Suspendisse a elementum arcu, a imperdiet elit. Curabitur diam neque, placerat ac mi vitae, blandit dictum ligula.

and I put the cursor for example in the second paragraph ('Nulla et arcu...') in the fifth sentence ('Aenan porttitor...') between the words `ex` and `quis`, how can I get the text of the current sentence up to the cursor position? the expected result should be `Aenean porttitor ex`?

Btw, the only result I can achieve is to get all the current sentence with this code:

```
await Word.run(async (context) => {    
        var sentences = context.document.getSelection().getTextRanges(['\n', '.', '?'], false);
        context.load(sentences);
        context.sync().then(() => {
            console.log(sentences.items[0].text);
        });         
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried running the code under the debugger attached to observe values at runtime?

Comment: Yes Eugene, the debugger it is not a good help because to obtain the correct values the script must call context.load/context.sync and wait the result, develop in this way is very annoying